# GWT 2.7.0 with chrome version 69 not loading java source files

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am using GWT 2.7.0 and I noticed that on chrome (69.0.3497.100 for example, on Mac OS in superdev mode, the java source map files are not loaded anymore. Each console error or info message points to the generate .js file and not the original java files, which makes almost impossible to debug the code.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**
Searching for older versions of chromium, I noticed that the problem is only on Mac OS (I previously used Ubuntu 16) on gwt 2.7.0 exactly. I tested with gwt 2.8.1 and it worked but i cannot use it in my main project as it has deprecated dependecies that i cannot remove yet.

Comment: A comment would be nice from those who downvote without saying anything...

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: No. I still have this issue. I have no idea how to fix it. But i cannot switch to gwt 2.8 yet

Comment: I am on GWT 2.8.1 and this problem suddenly happened, any solution guys?